# Running custom trained yolov8 model on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson-nano, yolov8

I’ve custom trained a yolov8n model and I would like to run it on a Jetson Nano. Has anyone managed to do this? If yes, would you be so kind to help me out?

I’ve got a .pt of the custom trained model. The OS image offered by NVidia on their website is an Ubuntu 18.04 and I have run into many compatibility issues. I’m interested in finding out if anyone has managed to get yolo running on the Jetson specifically the yolov8n model from ultralytics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look at this documentation.](https://i7y.org/en/yolov8-on-jetson-nano/)
Just run Python code after opening/activating the environment.

Using a CLI: `python3 yolov8_code.py`

Using VS Code:

- After installation, open VS Code.
- In the top-middle command palette,type "Python: Select Interpreter" and press enter.
- Select the environment for YOLOv8 and run your code using VS Code.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. it worked! any clues on how to improve the performance? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully managed to run YOLOv8n detection model in Jetson Nano with an unofficial [Ubuntu 20.04 image](https://github.com/Qengineering/Jetson-Nano-Ubuntu-20-image) by Qengineering.

Afterwards, you only need to install Ultralytics and run the YOLO model as usual.

However, from my experience there's an issue with the model in Jetson Nano. The program running the model uses high memory (2GB+), even when using CLI (`yolo predict ...`). So, I can't do anything unless running the detection program in Jetson Nano.

In conclusion, it works but raises another problem. Let's see if you or anyone has the same problem.